# Best tool for video conference app using Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, sencha-touch, smartphone

I'm going to build a video conference application using Phone-gap for cross platform (iPad and Android).

Which is the best tool to use: Sencha Touch, jQuery mobile, or something else?

Comment: This is probably too discursive for SO, and it's probably subjective - "best" depends on your exact requirements, and can really only be determined by testing several of the leading systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is the best Sencha Touch mobile framework for a number of reasons ...

1. It is built on HTML5
2. Smoother scrolling and animations
3. Native packaging
4. Device support